# How to show multiple tooltip in xrange highcarts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to show some tooltip on a particular time on the xrange Highcharts on chart render , but there is no existing feature for that, is there any possibilities to show a tooltip like below

From this example I found that annotation can be used to show some message, I tried to utilize this.

```js
function annotateChart({
  text,
  value
}) {
  const annons = this.annons;

  const label = this.renderer.label(text, 0, 0).attr({
    stroke: 'red',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    align: 'center',
    zIndex: 99,
    class: 'newText'
  }).add();

  annons.push({
    label,
    value
  });
}

function redrawAnnons() {
  const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
  const yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

  this.annons.forEach(ann => {
    ann.label.animate({
      x: xAxis.toPixels(ann.value),
      y: yAxis.toPixels(-2.0)
    });
  });
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    marginTop: '55',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.annons = [];

        [{
          text: ['min', 'time', 'data', 'bluetooth'],
          value: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2)
        }, {
          text: 'max',
          value: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 21, 5)
        }].forEach(obj => {
          annotateChart.call(this, obj);
        });

        redrawAnnons.call(this)
      },
      redraw: redrawAnnons
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    minPadding: 0,
    opposite: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
    reversed: true,
    lineColor: '#2c2d39',
    lineWidth: 1
  },
  series: [{
    name: ' ',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      y: 0,
      partialFill: 0.25
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
      y: 2
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }]

});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

I'm not sure whether this is the correct approach, if there is any other way to achieve this, also the tooltip is shown on the chart top margin

> marginTop: '55'

Tooltip With more that 2 data is affecting the highchart responsiveness.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue here exactly. Could you be more precise about what you're trying to achieve? Have you tried` tooltip.formatter`?

Comment: for a particular time I need to show the details like battery low,location turned off, in a static tooltip which will be visible all the time , consider like it's an annotation, but is it possible to show the tooltip/annotation outside the highcharts axis , like you see in the image above. https://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/1a5dyxnp/16/

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mqey7gcu/

Comment: Is this solution resolves the issue?

Comment: actually I used another approach to render that tooltip in a div outside the highcharts based on the hover, anyhow thanks for the concern!